# How to pass a managed bean as param at a facelet template

Tags: java, null, facelets, managed-bean, param

I'm having a lot of trouble trying to pass a managed bean as param at a facelet template.
I'm trying to create a variable at a facelet template and pass its value through ui:param, but i'm constantly having the "Target Unreachable, identifier 'bean' resolved to null" error.
I already tryed to set it like:

```
<p:commandButton value="Save" actionListener="#{sessionScope[bean].save}" />
```

and it again do not work.

Can anyone help me please?

Here is the code:

crud_template.xhtml

```
<ui:define name="content">

    <h:form>
        <ui:insert name="create_form">
            <!-- Default -->
        </ui:insert>

        <br />
        <br />
        <p:separator />
        <p:commandButton value="Save" actionListener="#{bean.save}" />
        <p:commandButton value="Cancel" actionListener="#{bean.cancel}" />
    </h:form>

</ui:define>
```

familyPersist.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/templates/crud_template.xhtml">

    <ui:param name="bean" value="#{familyBean}" />

    <ui:define name="create_form">
        <h:panelGrid columns="3">
            <h:outputLabel value="Name*:" for="itemName" />
            <p:inputText id="itemName" required="true"
                value="#{familyBean.item.nmFamily}" />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
</html>
```

CrudBean.java

```
public abstract class CrudBean<T> {

    protected T item;

    private String redirect() {
        return "/pages/protected/" + getEntityName() + "List.jsf";
    }

    public String save() {
        return redirect();
    }

    public String cancel() {
        return redirect();
    }

    public abstract String getEntityName();

    /**
     * @return the item
     */
    public T getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    /**
     * @param item the item to set
     */
    public void setItem(T item) {
        this.item = item;
    }

}
```

FamilyBean.java

```
@Model
public class FamilyBean extends CrudBean<Family> {

    public FamilyBean() {
        item = new Family();
    }

    @Override
    public String getEntityName() {
        return "Family";
    }

}
```

And finally, the error:

```
22:11:50,178 GRAVE [javax.faces.event] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4) javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable, identifier 'bean' resolved to null
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getTarget(AstValue.java:98)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:244)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:39)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:153)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:769)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
    at org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:62)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:489)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50)
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

**EDIT:**

I create my project using this maven command:

```
mvn archetype:generate \
    -DarchetypeArtifactId=jboss-javaee6-webapp-archetype \
    -DarchetypeGroupId=org.jboss.spec.archetypes \
    -DarchetypeVersion=7.1.1.CR2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I read from the documents, @Model is equivalent to @ManagedBean with RequestScoped.

So if I try to fix the same, I can do something like:

**ui:param**

```
<ui:param name="bean" value="familyBean" />
```

In **crud_template.xhtml**:

```
<p:commandButton value="Save" actionListener="#{requestscope[bean].save}" />
```

Try this out, this should work.

**Edit:**

I did try to replicate the same, and was able to work it out.

I am posting the sample code here for your reference.

Also would like to share one thing:
If the bean is not inject once inside the xhtml, you will not be able to get the reference out of it.

```
Template page:

<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j">

<h:head></h:head>

<h:form>
    <ui:insert name="create_form">
        <!-- Default -->
    </ui:insert>

    <br />
    <br />

    <h:commandLink id="link" value="Name Converted">
        <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{requestScope[beantt].convertNameToUpperCase2}" execute="dateOfExpense" render="dateOfExpense" />
    </h:commandLink>

</h:form>
</ui:composition>
```

Sample test page:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j">

<f:view>
    <h:body>
        <ui:composition template="testTemplate.xhtml">

            <ui:param name="beantt" value="helloWorld" />

            <ui:define name="create_form">
                <h:panelGrid columns="3">
                    <h:outputLabel value="Name*:" for="itemName" />
                    <h:inputText size="20" value="#{helloWorld.name}" id="dateOfExpense"/>
                    <h:outputText value="#{requestScope}" />
                </h:panelGrid>

            </ui:define>

        </ui:composition>

    </h:body>
</f:view>

</ui:composition>
```

Backend bean class: (Not working with archetype)

```
 @Named("helloWorld")   //@Model was not available in my project
 public class HelloWorldBean {

    private String name;

    //Getters and Setters

    Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HelloWorldBean.class);

    public void convertNameToUpperCase2(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
         LOG.debug("Inside Bean");
         name = name.toUpperCase();
    }
 }
```

**UPDATED BEAN CLASS**

```
 @javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean(name="helloWorld")
 @javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped
 public class HelloWorldBean {

private String name;

// Getters and Setters

// Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HelloWorldBean.class);

public void convertNameToUpperCase2(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
    // LOG.debug("Inside Bean");
    name = name.toUpperCase();
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

I have also displayed all the available variables in request scope, this will help in finding out whether the key being looked for was actually available or not.

**Update**
This is my observation so far. If you try to wire @Named, @Model (it doesn't work well with UI, means cannot resolve in xhtmls).

CDI is more like, injecting services into the controllers or here ManagedBean.

e.g.  Sample demonstrating the CDI:

```
@Named("testCon")
public class TestConsumer {

public String convertNameToUpperCase2(String name) {
    // LOG.debug("Inside Bean");
    return  name.toUpperCase();
}
```

}

@javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean(name="helloWorld")
   @javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped
   public class HelloWorldBean {

```
@Inject
@Named("testCon")
private TestConsumer test;

private String name;

// Getters and Setters

// Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HelloWorldBean.class);

public void convertNameToUpperCase2(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
    name = test.convertNameToUpperCase2(name);
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
 }
```

Comment: That leave me the follow error: `actionListener="#{requestScope[bean].save}": Target Unreachable, 'familyBean' returned null`

Comment: I tryed to execute the exact code you passed me, but it again give me the same error: `/WEB-INF/templates/testTemplate.xhtml @26,54 listener="#{requestScope[beantt].convertNameToUpperCase2}": Target Unreachable, 'helloWorld' returned null: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /WEB-INF/templates/testTemplate.xhtml @26,54 listener="#{requestScope[beantt].convertNameToUpperCase2}": Target Unreachable, 'helloWorld' returned null`, how can the code run beautifully there and here don't... maybe the pom.xml is importing some dependencies that in yours is different?

Comment: i updated the question and put the mvn command i used to create the project... maven archetype...

Comment: Did you create the getter and setter of name and I had printed all the variables available in requestscope didyou see the key helloWorld there?

Comment: Ok I will check in thus archetype in sometime, but I highly doubt if that can be an issue.

Comment: @mandaji looks like you were correct, in analyzing that issues could be related different environments. I have tested on the archetype you supplied and have changed the HelloWorldBean class, have a look at it.

Comment: really thank you, that works pretty well!!! But I don't understand why the `@Named` or the `@Model` didn't work. Maybe because of its scope?

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the above suggestions but no luck.
The only thing that finally worked for me is to use Parentheses '()' when invoking a method. I guess that the property not found exception should have been a clue that it confused property with method. I believe this to be a bug with facelets as it is inconsistent with traditional JSF actionListener and action methods invocation.

the example above should work with:

`<p:commandButton value="Save" actionListener="#{bean.save()}" />`

where

`<ui:param name="bean" value="#{familyBean}" />`